# Complex Update Query on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, sql-update

I have three tables:

- **School**: SchoolID, SchoolName, City, State,...
- **Student**: StudentID, SchoolID (fk), FirstName, LastName, Birthdate,...
- **StudentTest**: StudentTestID, StudentID (fk), TestDate, Grade,...

Sometimes I know that students transfer to different schools, in which case I simply change `Student.SchoolID` to the new `SchoolID`.

Often I *do not* find out a student has transferred, in which case I end up with two students with identical FirstName, LastName, Birthdate but different SchoolID. I'll call these duplicate students (an index prevents all four fields from being identical). When this occurs, I have to go to the `StudentTest` table and change `StudentTest.StudentID` to match the new `StudentID`. After all the tests are transferred to the "new" student I can delete the old student record.

In cleaning up a SQL Server database with 35,000 students, I have 1600 students duplicated, with varying numbers of tests connected with the duplicate students.

I can select the tests of duplicate students so that they are grouped together, taken from a view (`vwTestList`, that combines some student information with test information):

```
SELECT 
    a.SchoolID as SchID, a.StudentID as StudID, a.StudentTestID as TestID, 
    a.LastName as LName, a.FirstName as FName, 
    a.Birthdate as BDate, a.Testdate as Tdate, a.Grade
FROM 
    dbo.vwTestList a
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         firstname, lastname, BirthDate, SchoolID
     FROM 
         dbo.vwTestList
     GROUP BY 
         firstname, lastname, BirthDate, SchoolID
     HAVING 
         COUNT(*) > 1) b ON a.firstname = b.firstname
                         AND a.lastname = b.lastname
                         AND a.BirthDate = b.BirthDate
                         AND a.SchoolID <> b.SchoolID
ORDER BY 
    a.LastName, a.FirstName, a.BirthDate, a.Testdate DESC
```

Sample Results:

```
SchID   StudID  TestID LName    FName   Bdate       TDate      Grade
----------------------------------------------------------------------
461     16172   142773  Auk     Jay     2000-06-29  2010-04-13  4.7 
461     16172   136350  Auk     Jay     2000-06-29  2009-04-14  3.7 
146     5234    128517  Auk     Jay     2000-06-29  2008-04-01  2.7 
146     5234    123560  Auk     Jay     2000-06-29  2007-04-10  1.7
```

However, I cannot figure out an update query that will change all the tests for each set of duplicate students to the `StudentID` of the most recent test in the set. In the example, all of Jay Auk's tests should end up with a `StudentID` of 16172. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @marc_s. Just learning my way around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following example and see if this helps you get started. This example can be run in SSMS.

```
-- replicate environment --

DECLARE @TestView TABLE (
    SchID INT, StudID INT, TestID INT, LName VARCHAR(30), FName VARCHAR(30), BDate DATETIME, TDate DATETIME, Grade DECIMAL(10,1)
)

INSERT INTO @TestView (
    SchID, StudID, TestID, LName, FName, BDate, TDate, Grade
)
VALUES
  ( 461, 16172, 142773, 'Auk', 'Jay', '2000-06-29', '2010-04-13', 4.7 )
, ( 461, 16172, 136350, 'Auk', 'Jay', '2000-06-29', '2009-04-14', 3.7 )
, ( 146, 5234, 128517, 'Auk', 'Jay', '2000-06-29', '2008-04-01', 2.7 )
, ( 146, 5234, 123560, 'Auk', 'Jay', '2000-06-29', '2007-04-10', 1.7 )
, ( 152, 17899, 123561, 'Gates', 'Bill', '1955-10-28', '2007-04-15', 4.7 )
, ( 152, 17899, 123562, 'Gates', 'Bill', '1955-10-28', '2007-04-14', 3.7 )
, ( 157, 5235, 123563, 'Gates', 'Bill', '1955-10-28', '2007-04-01', 2.7 )
, ( 157, 5235, 123564, 'Gates', 'Bill', '1955-10-28', '2007-04-10', 1.7 );

-- starting data --

SELECT * FROM @TestView;
```

Returns:

```
+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------+
| SchID | StudID | TestID | LName | FName |          BDate          |          TDate          | Grade |
+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------+
|   461 |  16172 | 142773 | Auk   | Jay   | 2000-06-29 00:00:00.000 | 2010-04-13 00:00:00.000 | 4.7   |
|   461 |  16172 | 136350 | Auk   | Jay   | 2000-06-29 00:00:00.000 | 2009-04-14 00:00:00.000 | 3.7   |
|   146 |   5234 | 128517 | Auk   | Jay   | 2000-06-29 00:00:00.000 | 2008-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2.7   |
|   146 |   5234 | 123560 | Auk   | Jay   | 2000-06-29 00:00:00.000 | 2007-04-10 00:00:00.000 | 1.7   |
|   152 |  17899 | 123561 | Gates | Bill  | 1955-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2007-04-15 00:00:00.000 | 4.7   |
|   152 |  17899 | 123562 | Gates | Bill  | 1955-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2007-04-14 00:00:00.000 | 3.7   |
|   157 |   5235 | 123563 | Gates | Bill  | 1955-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2007-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2.7   |
|   157 |   5235 | 123564 | Gates | Bill  | 1955-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2007-04-10 00:00:00.000 | 1.7   |
+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------+
```

You can see the starting values above.

Continuing on...

```
-- update the StudID to the most recent test StudID for student --

UPDATE @TestView
SET
    StudID = Tests.MostRecentID
FROM @TestView vwTestList
CROSS APPLY (

    SELECT TOP 1 StudID AS MostRecentID FROM @TestView vw 
    WHERE 
        vw.LName = vwTestList.LName 
        AND vw.FName = vwTestList.FName 
    ORDER BY vw.TDate DESC

) AS Tests;

-- view results --

SELECT * FROM @TestView;
```

Returns:

```
+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------+
| SchID | StudID | TestID | LName | FName |          BDate          |          TDate          | Grade |
+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------+
|   461 |  16172 | 142773 | Auk   | Jay   | 2000-06-29 00:00:00.000 | 2010-04-13 00:00:00.000 | 4.7   |
|   461 |  16172 | 136350 | Auk   | Jay   | 2000-06-29 00:00:00.000 | 2009-04-14 00:00:00.000 | 3.7   |
|   146 |  16172 | 128517 | Auk   | Jay   | 2000-06-29 00:00:00.000 | 2008-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2.7   |
|   146 |  16172 | 123560 | Auk   | Jay   | 2000-06-29 00:00:00.000 | 2007-04-10 00:00:00.000 | 1.7   |
|   152 |  17899 | 123561 | Gates | Bill  | 1955-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2007-04-15 00:00:00.000 | 4.7   |
|   152 |  17899 | 123562 | Gates | Bill  | 1955-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2007-04-14 00:00:00.000 | 3.7   |
|   157 |  17899 | 123563 | Gates | Bill  | 1955-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2007-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 2.7   |
|   157 |  17899 | 123564 | Gates | Bill  | 1955-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2007-04-10 00:00:00.000 | 1.7   |
+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------+
```

The StudID has been updated to the most recent Test StudID for each row. Joining on the name makes me nervous, but if you don't have another unique way to guarantee a student match ( e.g. two students have the same name ) then there may not be a lot of other options.

As always verify your data before actually running your update, but this should help you get started.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. Duplicate students are determined by FName, LName, _and_ BDate, so the odds of an unwanted join are fairly slim.

Comment: That's great. Funny, the date of birth was so obvious that I missed it, lol.